# How to fix background red color in custom textinputlayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

`Textinputlayout` background shows a red color after giving a custom background to edit text when the error occurs.

I'm using custom textinputlayout for placing `app:hintEnabled="false"`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvFirstNameSecondTest"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/tilLastNameSecondTest"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFirstNameThirdTest">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_form_filling"
        android:id="@+id/etTilLastNameSecondTest"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My Kotlin File

```
class FarmerForm : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var context: Context
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_farmer_form)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    context = this
    val updateProfileValidation = AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.TEXT_INPUT_LAYOUT)
    updateProfileValidation.addValidation(
        this,
        R.id.tilFirstNameFirstTest,
        RegexTemplate.NOT_EMPTY,
        R.string.txt_enter_valid_name
    )
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener {
        if(updateProfileValidation.validate()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Form Validated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            if(tilFirstNameFirstTest.error!=null){
                etTilFirstNameFirstTest.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_form_error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Drawable XML file

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
<corners android:radius="@dimen/margin_4dp"/>
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#ff0000"/>
<padding
    android:left="8dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:right="8dp"/>
```

How to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

To change the background color of a filled text field you can:

- set the **`boxBackgroundColor`** attribute on your `TextInputLayout`
- use the methods **`textInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundColorResource()`** and **`textInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundColor()`**.

Also to change the stroke of the `TextInputLayout` you can use:

- `textInputLayout.setBoxCornerRadii()` to change the corner radii
- `textInputLayout.setBoxStrokeColor()` to change the color of the stroke

Finally use `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` instead of an `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

To set the background colour for your TextInput Field use the correct format for the TextInputLayout, instead of the code below,

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvFirstNameSecondTest"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
android:id="@+id/tilLastNameSecondTest"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
app:hintEnabled="false"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_4dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_16dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFirstNameThirdTest">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_form_filling"
    android:id="@+id/etTilLastNameSecondTest"/>
```

use this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvFirstNameSecondTest"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
android:id="@+id/tilLastNameSecondTest"
**app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/green"**
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
app:hintEnabled="false"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_4dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_16dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFirstNameThirdTest">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etTilLastNameSecondTest"/>
```

This changes are: Replace EditText with "**com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText**" and add "**app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/red**"". this will get rid of the error you're getting and you will also be able to achieve the style you want the InputBox to have

Comment: thanks for the reply bro. I want a custom background where I need to show when I get an error. Anyways problem solved by creating custom textinputlayout.

Comment: Great @LakshmiNarayanaNidadala kindly mark correct or vote up if this solution solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can add `editTextBackground` color in your activity theme style, something like

**styles.xml file**

```
 <style name="BaseTheme_FullScreen2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
            <item name="editTextBackground">@color/yellow</item>
            <item name="actionBarSize">48dp</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarSize">56dp</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
            <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/bg_color</item>
            <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
            <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay</item>
  </style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".modules.mainModule.homeScreen.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/BaseTheme_FullScreen2"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"></activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro. I also tried that one, but later I created one custom textinputlayout problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

for custom textinputlayout, You just need to create a custom EditText and override the getBackground() method of it to return a new drawable. That way TextInputLayout won't be able to set color filter on the EditText's background, since you do not return EditText's background, but some another drawable. See below:

```
@Override
public Drawable getBackground() {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.some_drawable);
}
```

and use the custom EditText inside TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CustomEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text_bg" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro. I solved it by creating one custom textinputlayout.